# NSUserDefaults and iCloud

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, synchronization, icloud

My app is one I have asked about before.  It is an XML parser that shows a number of items from the XML equal to the number of days the app has been opened.  My question is mainly this:  I have nothing set up with iCloud in version 1.0.  I will soon be releasing an iPad version of the app due to its popularity, and am concerned that those who have had the app for a while on iPhone will now be reset back to Day 1 on the iPad version.  I found [MKiCloudSync](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKiCloudSync) on GitHub and wondered if this would be something good to implement so that the app always stays synced across all devices?  If it does, would adding it in version 1.1 of the app automatically sync with existing libraries, or would they have to update the iPhone version first, let it sync, and then get it for iPad?  Basically just want it to stay synced.

Here is the AppDelegate code I use to store the NSUserDefault Values.  Although, some of the NSUserDefaults can get changed in other classes.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    sleep(3);

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![defaults integerForKey:@"totalDays"]) {

        // if there is no value for the key, set it to 1
        [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"totalDays"];

    }
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"currentDate"]) {
        [defaults setObject:@"32 01" forKey:@"currentDate"];
    }
    if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"marked"]) {
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"marked"];

    }
    if (![defaults arrayForKey:@"checkedrows"]) {
        NSMutableArray *arr1  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults arrayForKey:@"checkedrows"]];
    }
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MM"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    [dateFormat release];

    NSString *checkdate = [defaults objectForKey:@"currentDate"];

    if (![dateString isEqualToString:checkdate]) {
        NSInteger currentnumber = [defaults integerForKey:@"totalDays"];

        [defaults setObject:dateString forKey:@"currentDate"];
        [defaults setInteger:currentnumber+1 forKey:@"totalDays"];
    }

 [defaults synchronize];

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"enteredfore");
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    // format it
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MM"];

    // convert it to a string
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    // free up memory
    [dateFormat release];

    NSString *checkdate = [defaults objectForKey:@"currentDate"];
    NSLog(@"hereitis%@", checkdate);

    if (![dateString isEqualToString:checkdate]) {
        NSInteger currentnumber = [defaults integerForKey:@"totalDays"];
        NSLog(@"The current number is %i", currentnumber);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EnteredForeground"
                                                            object:nil];
        [defaults setObject:dateString forKey:@"currentDate"];
        [defaults setInteger:currentnumber+1 forKey:@"totalDays"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you look at the source code of MKiCloudSync (which is actually very short), you'll see that it simply stores the entire user defaults dictionary in iCloud whenever any of it changes.

Whenever anything in iCloud changes, it overwrites all the local user defaults with those stored in iCloud.

There is no concept of conflict resolution or anything like that, it'll simply take all the values from the device where they were last changed. For your use case this basically means that there is a good chance that the existing data on the iPhone is overwritten by the initial (probably empty) data that is pushed from the new iPad version to iCloud.

Btw, you should *never* call `sleep` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (basically, it should rarely be necessary to call it at all, but it's especially bad in this method because if it doesn't finish quickly enough, your app can get killed by the system).

Comment: yip thats the word I needed :D conflict resolution -- your app on the iphone in this case could be reset!

Comment: Any suggestions for how other classes that would work, or a method I could use to handle the conflict resolution?

Comment: How about this...instead of calling MKiCloudSync when the app becomes active, I add a button to the UI Called Sync, and have THAT sync it?  This way, the user can choose which device to sync, and when to sync it?  It wouldn't be a perfect solution as it wouldn't sync each time, but would at least solve issue of new devices overwriting ones that have been running for 50 days as Daji-Djan said.

Or...have a UIAlertView pop up each time the app is preparing to close asking if the user wants to sync the data?

Comment: https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDiCloudSync provides a delegate for conflict handling

Comment: it is basically a complete rewrite.. it provides a method that is called before a sync. there you can present a uialert or merge it without asking the user (if possible one should not ask him anything)

Comment: @Daij-Djan I am not using ARC so it gives me an synthesize of 'weak' property only allowed in ARC or GC mode error message.  Also getting warning that it can't find the method 'start' on DDiCloudSync method.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Here is my AppDelegate:`- init
{if (self = [super init]) {
        [DDiCloudSync start];
 }
 return self;
}
- (NSDictionary*)mergedDefaultsForUpdatingCloud:(NSDictionary*)dictInCloud withLocalDefaults:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    NSMutableDictionary *newdict = dict.mutableCopy;
    newdict[@"merged"] = @"to icloud";
    return newdict;
}
- (NSDictionary*)mergedDefaultsForUpdatingLocalDefaults:(NSDictionary*)dict withCloud:(NSDictionary*)dictInCloud {
    NSMutableDictionary *newdict = dict.mutableCopy;
    newdict[@"merged"] = @"from icloud";
    return newdict;
}
`call start in finish

Comment: Mkicloudsync was arc as well :p
Ill change that tonight though

Comment: a) you dont set the delegate so the methods dont get called, b) your code is hopefully just a demo .. there has to be some more logic in the app specific merge methods..

Comment: @Daij-Djan a)Ok, when I set the delegate using the method you showed in sample class, it gave an error message.  b)  So, if I understand right, on the mergedDefaultsForUpdatingLocalDefaults method, I need to have custom actions for the app in there to replace the keys that are setup in the NSUserDefaults?  It just doesn't replace it all automatically?

Comment: without any logic, this is behaves just like MKiCloudSync but as we keep saying you need some conflict handling! what error message?

Answer (score 0):

it will work fine technically but the result may be bad... there should be some 'conflict handling' / making one device the master...

let me explain with an example:

iphone with app 1.0 is running on device A and has been used 50 days
=> doesnt care about icloud

now ipad with app 1.1 is running for 5 days 
=> writes its settings to icloud

now device A's app is updated to 1.1
=> sees icloud. WOULD need to merge changes... it cant just use the icloud content, as it would reset device A to some earlier state that the new ipad saved

Comment: Any suggestions for how I could handle conflict resolution, either rewriting some of the MKiCloud class, or handling it in y other classes?

Comment: https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDiCloudSync provides a delegate for conflict handling

Comment: it is basically a complete rewrite.. it provides a method that is called before a sync. there you can present a uialert or merge it without asking the user (if possible one should not ask him anything)

Comment: Thanks.  One other thing I seem to be having issues with.  I have iCloud enabled in the app id, and provisioning profiles with that app id.  In the Target Summary, I enable entitlements, checkmark Enable iCloud and use the Bundle ID for Store identifier.  However, with even the MKiCloudSync Class I mentioned in OP, it wasn't syncing anything.  Is there anything else I have to do in my target to setup the ability to iCloud sync?

Comment: dont know ill do some more tests tomorrow evening. I only looked at how it should work :) I also added a unit test so it should work the same as before + the conflict handling

Comment: Cool, I've been drug out today shopping so I won't be able to test anything out either for a bit.